# Background images are not being referenced correctly

Tags: image, background-image, file-location

Ok, first off, I know that the code referenced below has to do with a Joomla! site, however, I have had this problem on more than one site, not all of them using the Joomla! framework.

Now the problem:

I have some background images that are being referenced in my CSS stylesheet as:

```
background: url(../images/j_header_middle.png) repeat-x;
```

However, when the page is loaded into the web browser it is being referenced as:

```
background:url(http://64.19.142.11/www.outoftheblueinc.net/administrator/templates/bluestork/images/j_header_middle.png) repeat-x
```

I have done some searching on the web and have not been able to find a proper explanation as to why the images are being referenced this way.  If I go into the console and remove the IP address from the file location it works just fine.  I just have no idea why it is being added to the file location in the first place.

Any constructive ideas as to why this is happening are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you've found a satisfying explanation for this. If not then at least this post will serve as more data. My website recently had this problem too. In my javascript, I linked with the google hosted version of jQuery UI 1.8.18. Everything seemed ok for weeks until today when my browser kept trying to connect with 64.19.142.11. This link is the culprit.

```
http://64.19.142.11/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/cupertino/images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f2f5f7_1x100.png
```

That png file is an image resource specified by jQuery UI. I only started to see the problem today and I can't be sure whether it just started happening or the host with IP 64.19.142.11 recently went down. For weeks, jQuery ui 1.8.18 works fine.

Finally, after downgrading to 1.8.17 the problem seems to go away (no weird IP injection).